# Excel range to plane string

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read an Excel range to a variable of type string.

Currently I have achieved it with a work around. I copied the range to clipboard and used a `ReadClipBoard` function that reads the clipboard as assigns to variable. This method is not efficient and also some times it gives error due to clipboard issues with VBA.

Workaround Code:

```
 Dim variable as string
 Range("A1:C5").Copy
 variable = ReadClipBoard()'Function that returns clipboard text
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not too clear here on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to access the values within the range?

Comment: Eg when we select a range of cells in excel , then copy it and paste it to notepad we get a plain text.I want that plain text to be in a variable.Its done but i am looking for a better way to achieve it , I thought Range("A1:C5").Text would do it but it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

This will turn each line into a tab-separated string and the whole range into a line-separated string.

```
Public Function RangeToText(ByRef r As Range)

    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim aOutput() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    'Put range into a two dim array
    vaData = r.Value

    'Make one dim array the same number of rows
    ReDim aOutput(1 To UBound(vaData, 1))

    'Make strings With tabs out of each row
    'and put into one dim array
    For i = LBound(vaData, 1) To UBound(vaData, 1)
        aOutput(i) = Join(wf.Index(vaData, i), vbTab)
    Next i

    'join all the strings into one multi-line string
    RangeToText = Join(aOutput, vbNewLine)

End Function
```

In the Immediate Window

```
?rangetotext(sheet1.Range("A1:C5"))
Here    Here    Here
is  is  is
some    some    some
column 1    column 2    column 3
text    text    text
```

The Index worksheet function is used to process only one row at a time because Join requires a one dimensional array

Comment: This solution is nice one but some points: 1.wraps the output string in double quotation marks .2.It gives error when only one cell is used as range.

Comment: What do you mean it wraps the string in quotes? It doesn't do that on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading more than once cell, then the variable would be an **array**  For example:

```
Sub ArrayDemo()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Range("A1:C5")
   variable = r
End Sub
```

is nearly equivalent to :

```
Sub ArrayDemo2()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Range("A1:C5")
   Dim variable(1 To 5, 1 To 3) As Variant
   For i = 1 To 5
      For j = 1 To 3
         variable(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive way is to concatenate all the content into a string, is that ok for you?

```
Function ConcatCells(r as range, optional sep as string) as string
  dim c as range
  dim s as string

  s=""
  if sep is missing then sep=" "
  for each c in r.cells
    s = s & c & sep
  next c
  s=left(s, len(s) - len(sep))
  ConcatCells=s
end sub
```